# infinite scrolling in lwc is repeating the record multiple times

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, scrolling

I am implementing custom activity timeline and trying to do custom infinite scrolling. The issue i am facing  is while scrolling last fetched records are getting repeated multiple times and then stops. On scrolling lots of debug logs are also getting generated. I have tried using boolean variable in lwc javascript, but in that case it scrolls till **June** and then stops scrolling.

My Standard Timeline contains task till April

[image]

My Custom Timeline when doing scrolling this is happening below

April May is coming very below when the scrolling stops

[image]

JS -

```
connectedCallback() {

    getActivityTimeline({ recordId: this.rowdetails.idtoupdate, includeChildren: false, pageSize: this.rowLimit, pageNumber: this.pageNumber, lastActivityDate: null })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
            this.timelineGroups = result.map((v, i) => ({ ...v, sectionName: `Section${i}`, isExpanded: true }));
            this.activeSections = this.timelineGroups.map((v) => v.sectionName);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.isLoaded = false;
            this.error = error;
            this.showToast(this.error, 'Error')
        });

}
```

onscroll function -

```
 handleScroll(event) {
        if (event.target.scrollTop > event.target.scrollHeight - (event.target.offsetHeight * 2)) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.fetchMoreActivityTimeLine();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }



 fetchMoreActivityTimeLine() {
        const currentData = this.timelineGroups;
        let ldate = currentData[currentData.length - 1].items[currentData[currentData.length - 1].items.length - 1];
        let vDate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ldate)).activityDate;
        getActivityTimeline({ recordId: this.rowdetails.idtoupdate, includeChildren: false, pageSize: this.rowLimit, pageNumber: this.pageNumber, lastActivityDate: vDate })
            .then((data) => {
                this.fetchmoredata = data;
                console.log('Load data');
                if (data.length !== 0) {
                    this.timelineGroups = this.timelineGroups.concat(data);
                    console.log(this.timelineGroups);
                    console.log(this.timelineGroups.length);
                }
            }
            );
    }
```

Apex -

The SOQL which is running behind is below . I can't add all the apex as it is quite big one as i have use a wrapper to group those task , but this is the main soql

```
if(lastActivityDate !=null){    
    taskList = [SELECT Id, ActivityDate, Description, IsRecurrence, OwnerId, Owner.Name, Priority, Status, Subject, 
                           TaskSubtype, Type, WhatId, What.Name, WhoId, Who.Name
                           FROM Task
                           WHERE (WhatId IN: whatIdSet OR WhoId IN: whoIdSet)
                           AND ActivityDate < :Date.valueof(lastActivityDate) ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 5]; 
    system.debug('taskList ' + taskList.size());
}else{
    taskList = [SELECT Id, ActivityDate, Description, IsRecurrence, OwnerId, Owner.Name, Priority, Status, Subject, 
                           TaskSubtype, Type, WhatId, What.Name, WhoId, Who.Name
                           FROM Task
                           WHERE (WhatId IN: whatIdSet OR WhoId IN: whoIdSet)
                           ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 5];
    system.debug('taskList ' + taskList.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript is queuing up multiple callbacks, which all then fire using the same data, because the `.then` method is asynchronous, so it won't get a chance to see the new data until potentially many callbacks have occurred. Make sure you're debouncing your timer:

```
_timerId;
handleScroll(event) {
    if (event.target.scrollTop > event.target.scrollHeight - (event.target.offsetHeight * 2)) {
        clearTimeout(this._timerId);
        this._timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            this.fetchMoreActivityTimeLine();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome sfdcfox.. new thing learnt today .. "debouncing".. thanks